# Overfishing dataset

Tags: data-request, geospatial, environment

We are joining a datathon tomorrow with the goal to get insight in the whole ocean overfishing situation and we are looking for data to prepare a little bit. Global Fishing Watch seems interesting however we cannot find the data online. Does anyone have any good open datasets that could be relevant for this project?

Comment: [Ask them](http://www.globalfishingwatch.org/#6).

Comment: Yes I did :) no response yet and because of the temporary nature I asked here

Comment: Maybe not 'Global', but for the US, I suspect this would be NOAA's responsibility.  (I think they're actually under the Department of Commerce, who would be the other group that might have it).  A  quick search for 'NOAA fishing data' found https://www.st.nmfs.noaa.gov/commercial-fisheries/ and http://www.nmfs.noaa.gov/gis/data/fisheries.htm

Answer (score 3):

- There are a bunch of sources [here](http://chuckrblog.blogspot.com/2016/04/overfishing-statistics.html). Look down below in the Sources section.
- [A PDF from FAO](http://www.fao.org/docrep/016/i2727e/i2727e01.pdf), part of the UN.
- [Status of fish stocks](http://www.fao.org/newsroom/common/ecg/1000505/en/stocks.pdf) from UN FAO.
- [State of the Ocean report for 2013](http://www.stateoftheocean.org/science/state-of-the-ocean-report/) from the International Program of the State of the Ocean.
- Commercial fishery, [Fish landing data](http://www.st.nmfs.noaa.gov/commercial-fisheries/commercial-landings/annual-landings/index). Here you choose your parameters like fish species, date range, and it outputs data in an HTML table or text file. You can also choose all US states, geographic region, or single states.
- [Fishwatch, from NOAA](http://www.fishwatch.gov/sustainable-seafood/by-the-numbers) has reports on: status of fish stocks ([2015 report here as pdf](http://www.nmfs.noaa.gov/sfa/fisheries_eco/status_of_fisheries/archive/2015/2015_status_of_stocks_updated.pdf)), fish landings, and US fisheries economics.

Don't let the increasing tonnage caught fool you. Catches of some species can increase due to better ability to find them and better technology in general.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't find data directly related to overfishing, you can look for 1) volume of catches 2) estimated stocks

- [This report](http://www.pewtrusts.org/en/research-and-analysis/reports/2016/05/netting-billions-a-global-valuation-of-tuna) is market oriented and provided numbers about fishing
- [Stock Assessment of Pacific Bluefin Tuna 2014](http://isc.fra.go.jp/pdf/Stock_assessment/PBF_2014_Exec_Summary_4-28-2014_gtd.pdf)

Source: [The Guardian one](http://www.theguardian.com/environment/2011/jul/07/tuna-species-risk-extinction) and [two](http://www.theguardian.com/sustainable-business/2016/may/02/overfishing-42bn-tuna-industry-risk-collapse?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=post&utm_term=tuna,overfishing&utm_campaign=Oceans&__surl__=IgNVx&__ots__=1464401858902&__step__=1).

Comment: Also Greenpeace lobbies against overfishing, you can find other sources from them.