# Dataset with the location of world fishing grounds

Tags: data-request

Does anyone know of a good source for the location of fishing grounds?

I have looked at the resources mentioned in [this](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7410/overfishing-dataset/7866#7866) question but have not found anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selected list of resources for data regarding world fishing grounds:
[Human Impacts to Marine Ecosystems](http://www.nceas.ucsb.edu/globalmarine/impacts): Data from the National Center for Ecological Analysis and Synthesis on human impacts to marine ecosystems. Includes fishing impacts, ocean acidification, sea surface temperature, pollutants and more.
[Aquamaps](http://www.aquamaps.org/): Standardised distribution maps for over 11,000 species of fish, marine mammals and invertebrates. *Data available for download under High Resolution Maps and Environmental Data links.
[Ecology Section](http://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/#ecology)
[U.S. Bathymetric & Fishing Maps - NOS Office of Coast Survey -- NOAA](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/bathymetry/relief.html)
[Global Data - dataMares](http://datamares.ucsd.edu/eng/global-data/) provides "free public downloadable data sets relating to various marine topics and coastal science research"...quick glance-> the first three general database portals are all applicable, and I'm assuming more of them are too. The "Focused Database Portals" section also looks highly relevant here.
[Global Fishery Databases](http://www.fao.org/fishery/topic/16054/en)
[Marine/Coastal GIS | Data & Image Portals (includes Metadata Catalogs and Atlases)](http://marinecoastalgis.net/data)
[OBIS-SEAMAP (Ocean Biogeographc Information System Spatial Ecological Analysis of Megavertebrate Populations) - spatially referenced database aggregating global marine mammal, seabird, sea turtle, ray, and shark observation data](http://seamap.env.duke.edu/)
[Sea Around Us](http://www.seaaroundus.org/)
[has extremely detailed data regarding catches](http://www.seaaroundus.org/data/#/fao/27?chart=catch-chart&dimension=eez&measure=tonnage&limit=10)
[GISFish](http://www.fao.org/fishery/gisfish/index.jsp)
[FAO (Food and Agriculture Organization of the United Nations)](http://www.fao.org/) has a Fisheries and Aquaculture Department which houses more data pertinent here:
[FIGIS - Fisheries Global Information System](http://www.fao.org/fishery/figis/en)
[DIAS - Database on Introductions of Aquatic Species](http://www.fao.org/fishery/dias/en)
[Atlas of Tuna and Billfish Catches](http://www.fao.org/fishery/statistics/tuna-atlas/en)
[Global Tuna Catches by Stock](http://www.fao.org/fishery/statistics/tuna-catches/en)
[NASO - National Aquaculture Sector Overview](http://www.fao.org/fishery/collection/naso/en)
[ASFA - Aquatic Sciences and Fisheries Abstract](http://www.fao.org/fishery/asfa/en)

This list of resources may have more information:

[Census of Marine Life](http://www.coml.org)
[Ocean Biogeographic Information System (OBIS)](http://www.iobis.org/)
[Global Biodiversity Information Facility (GBIF)](http://www.gbif.org/)
[Global Change Master Directory (GCMD)](http://gcmd.nasa.gov/)
[Marine Geospatial Ecology Tools (MGET)](http://code.env.duke.edu/projects/mget)
[Satellite Tracking and Analysis Tool (STAT)](http://www.seaturtle.org/stat/)

Comment: Awesome. More than a kick in the right direction.